# How can I represent a set in ampl into a vector in c++?

Tags: c++, vector, ampl

I have two sets in ampl to be implemented in c++, set NS and set S.
But I'm not understanding the set S very well.

```
set N ordered := {1..n};
set NS ordered := 1..(2**n-1);
set S {s in NS} := {i in N: (s div 2**(ord(i)-1)) mod 2 = 1};
```

If n = 4, I will have:

```
set N := 1 2 3 4

set NS := 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15;

set S[1] := 1;
set S[2] := 2;
set S[3] := 1 2;
set S[4] := 3;
set S[5] := 1 3;
set S[6] := 2 3;
set S[7] := 1 2 3;
set S[8] := 4;
set S[9] := 1 4;
set S[10] := 2 4;
set S[11] := 1 2 4;
set S[12] := 3 4;
set S[13] := 1 3 4;
set S[14] := 2 3 4;
set S[15] := 1 2 3 4;
```

The first set can be easily created.

```
vector <int> NS;
int auxMax = pow(2,n)-1;
for (int i = 0; i < auxMax; i++) {
    NS.push_back(i);
}
```

Although I know how the operators div (returns the truncated quotient when its left operand is divided by its right operand), mod (computes the remainder) and ord(returns the numerical position of [i] within the set N) work, I'm not able to make a struct of "for" to fed set S.
Can anyone help me understanding the generation of set S and transforming it to a vector in c++?

Thank you!

Comment: Where is `N` defined ? Can you describe what is type of S, is it an array of int, an array of array of boolean ?

Comment: Since set `NS` is `[1, 2, 3, ...., 2^n-1)`, then `ord(i)` will always equal `i-1` (if `ord` is 0 based right?

Answer (score 0):

Im not familiar with ampl, but I'll give it a go:
Assuming I understood that {} translates to some form of vector type.

Result is the following:

```
int main()
{
  const int n = 4;
  int NS = pow(2, n) - 1;

  std::vector< std::vector<int> > S;
  for (int s = 1; s <= NS; s++) // {s in NS}                                    
    {
      std::vector<int> iN;
      for (int ord_i = 1; ord_i <= n; ord_i++) // {i in N}                      
        {
          if ((s / (int)pow(2, ord_i - 1)) % 2 == 1)
            iN.push_back(ord_i);
        }
      S.push_back(iN);
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you a lot. But actually, set S is not a boolean set. I wrote the output of each set in the question.

Comment: Thanks @rbl for updating, I was able to find the solution. I was actually very close.

Comment: Thanks again @Tezirg. But when I try to print set S, I don't have exactly the same output as the one that ampl gives me. It lacks set with just node 1 (S[i] = {1}), and with our code, S[15] is empty. Do you know how can I fix it?

Comment: In c++ index start from 0. try printing S[0] up to S[14]. I have the correct output here.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Tezirg